# Copy excel table/list to another sheet filtered

Tags: excel

This seems really easy but I'm struggling to do this in excel. 
Consider the table:

```
Paul   Manager
John   Engineer
Ann    Engineer
Kate   IT Support
```

In a new sheet I want to get only the Engineers for example:

```
John   Engineer
Ann    Engineer
```

How can I copy the data filtered like this?

For clarification: this is not a 1 one thing I want to do. I want to be able to change the input data and see the changed data on the new sheet.

Answer (score 0):

1. Select second column
2. Click on "Sort & Filter" in the Ribbon
3. List on the down arrow
4. Check on "Engineer" checkbox
5. You should now only have data for Engineers
6. Select the data and copy!

See screenshot for clarity:

[image: Screen shot for clarity:]

Comment: Sorry for the confusion: for clarification: this is not a 1 one thing I want to do. I want to be able to change the input data and see the changed data on the new sheet.

Answer (score 0):

You need to [Copy visible cells only](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/copy-visible-cells-only-HA010244897.aspx),  after filtering the table data

```
Home -> Find and Select -> Goto Special -> Visible cells only-> OK-> Ctrl+C and Ctrl+V
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry for the confusion: for clarification: this is not a 1 one thing I want to do. I want to be able to change the input data and see the changed data on the new sheet.

Comment: With out VBA , all I can think of,  is using [Advanced table Filter and copy filtered results to different sheet](http://excelsemipro.com/2011/03/copy-data-to-another-worksheet-with-advanced-filter/)